# For update with separate select and update

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm facing an issue regarding `for update` query. I have two methods as following:

The first one select rows and return a map contains primary key and value.

```
public Map<String,String> method1() throws SQLException  {
    String sql = "select * from table where col1='someValue' for update";
    // ... do something and construct map, so map contains {colName, value}
    return map;
}
```

The second method takes the map from the first method, then update row based on the value of the map.

```
public boolean method2(String pk){
    String sql = "update tableName set value = 1234 where primaryKey = pk";
    // ... execute query and return boolean of if row affected
    return booleanValue;
}
```

In a third method, method 1 & 2 will execute.

```
public void method3(){
    // execute method1, get value from map
    method1();
    // some other operations need to be done here...
    // pass value to method2 and execute
    method(value);
}
```

I did some research, and I found out some posts say using `for update` should not open transaction for too long.

My question is: should I take `select..for update` and actual update separately?

Comment: That is impossible to answer based on the information provided. But you may want to consider using optimistic concurrency solution (eg with a 'revision' or 'version' column instead).